# Jquery draggable() prevents CSS resize from working

Tags: jquery, css, resize, draggable

If possible, I'd like to use JQuery's `draggable()` along with CSS's `resize`.  But the `draggable()` apparently prevents `resize` from working.  Demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/zHkQB/123/.  Any ideas on how to fix this?  I would use JQuery's `resizable()`, but that's not working either.

Comment: Use the jQueryUI `resizable()` instead: http://jsfiddle.net/zHkQB/124/

Comment: I would, except that's not working in my case either.

Comment: Check your console for errors, as you can see that it works fine in the fiddle you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Add `resizable()` to your jQuery:

`$("#dragResize").resizable().draggable()`

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, you need to add `resizable()` to your code, and remove the CSS call that allows the element to be resized. I've updated the Fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/r3kbjwgq/1/

Your issue was that the jQuery `resizable()` was conflicting with your CSS `resize:both` call, as when you click on the CSS created resize handle, you're interacting with the element. Having jQuery create the resize handle with:

```
$('#the-thing').resizable({
    handles: 'se'
});
```

You have the jQuery create a new resize handle as a separate element, allowing for both the resizing, and dragging of the element.